# What's the right way to check the available memory in Linux

Tags: linux, memory

Sorry for this entry level question,but I am got confused,so I want to let others to to help me clarify it

I use `free` command in linux to see the available memory inside it.

At first I think the value if come from *free* column in the first row,so in the picture below is **102532**,but I see in some other parts say that the available memory is **free** + **bufferes** + **cached**,so in the picture below is 102532 + 200904 + 5832244,which is **6135680**.

But when I use `free -t` or `vmstat -s |grep memory` I found the free memory is still around **102532**

Now, I am confused and I do not know shall I need to add more memory for this Linux system.

Can anyone help me to find which method is the right way to check the **available memory** in Linux(shall we need to consider buffered and cached memory as available memory?),and for the output in the picture below,shall I need to add more memory for it?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: What makes you think you need to add more memory?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that your "cached" value is just under 6GB means that the vast majority of you memory is being used to cache data rather than is in active use by applications.

The cache should be freed up as applications request memory and can, to an extent, be seen as "memory that is available to be used if needed but is currently being used to cache other data."

The cache is not *technically* free, as in empty and immediately available for use, but it is almost as good as.